# IBM raid configuration utility for checking disks health in windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, ibm

I know there is a great and simple tool for monitoring hp disks health: 
http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/

Is there something similar for IBM server?
My server - IBM X3630 X3, hardware raid - IBM ServeRAID M5015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you head to the [IBM Support Portal](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Downloads), add a new system (you'll need your system type - I think your's will start with 7377 ...), and click continue, you should be able to see your system listed in the window, and there should be something like Disk Controller and RAID Software Matrix. Follow that and you should find what you're looking for. I think the utility is called (or used to be at least) IBM ServeRaid Manager, but if you follow the links in the support portal you should find what you need easily enough.

Comment: Here is the link for what I found: https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=dmp&lang=en_US&S_PKG=director_x_520&cp=UTF-8&dlmethod=http